How do I do a fresh install of 24.04 onto a laptop that has 2 disk drives?
My laptop has two hard drives:

a 256 GB SSD
a 2TB SATA drive

I want to install Ubuntu on this laptop.
I want one, and only one, operating system. I assume I'll use the SATA drive for larger files and stuff (like movies), not the more use-intensive things (like programs).
I cannot figure out how to do this and have failed many times now.
When I use the Ubuntu Installer and get to the step "How do you want to install Ubuntu?" I have three main options.

Install alongside [old OS]. I do not want this.
Erase disk and install Ubuntu. This does not work because it picks one of the drives and installs on it, as though I wanted to dual boot. Which I do not.
Manual installation. Clearly I need to use this, but I cannot find any RELIABLE information on how to do so. I can easily find about a million Chat-GPT-generated "guides" that do not tell me what I need to know. And thus, I am here.

When I try to use the manual installer. I see sda (256 GB), sdb (2 TB), and sdc (8 GB).  I assume that the sdc is the USB drive from which I am attempting to install Ubuntu.
I do not know what partitions to make, or how large to make them, or on which drives to put those partitions.
Edit: Or at what "mount point" to put anything at all.
I also do not know what the drop-down in the lower left is indicating with "Device for boot loader installation." Is it asking the source, or asking me to pick where I want to boot in the future, or what?
Please help. This feels like it should be very simple, but I have looked for hours and cannot find anything that wasn't written by an unreliable chatbot.

I think you should wait until 24.04.1 is released or install 22.04, the fastest way for you to do what you want is to backup everything you need, delete all partitions with op ssd and let the installer take care of installing everything on ssd (though I think it is not recommended way).

What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Some require special settings whether 22.04 or 24.04. How much RAM? UEFI system (since 2012) or old BIOS only system. Many vendors call UEFI as BIOS. My Dell says BIOS, but inside it, it then says only UEFI install supported. You want gpt partitioning on both drives.  Partition sizes are vary opinion related as depends on how you are using system. New user probably better to have just ESP & / (root). Then format larger drive into desired partition(s) and create mount points, and give yourself ownership & permissions.

See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml, or read man hier.
It explains where things go. Departing from the Standard places one at risk of becoming broken and unsupportable.
